# How do I reference an XML attribute which begins with an @ symbol using KQL extractjson function?

Tags: json, xml, azure, attributes, kql

I'm trying to access an XML elements attribute in Azure KQL having converted it to JSON using parse_xml. However the extractjson function doesn't seem to like the use of the @ notation. See the code snippet below.

```
let input_xml="<NetAmount currency=\"USD\">150.00</NetAmount>";
let sJson=tostring(parse_xml(input_xml));
let amount=extractjson("$.NetAmount.#text", sJson);
let sCurrency=extractjson($.NetAmount.@currency, sJson);
print input_xml, amount,  sJson //, sCurrency;
```

If you run the above code it will work. However if you comment in the reference to sCurrency in the print statement, it barfs with an error which reads:

*There was a problem running your query. Please try again later*

Any ideas how you reference the currency attribute in the extractjson function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to use `extract_json()`, rather you can simply use dynamic object accessors: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/dynamic#dynamic-object-accessors

```
print input_xml = "<NetAmount currency=\"USD\">150.00</NetAmount>"
| project sJson = parse_xml(input_xml)
| project amount = sJson.NetAmount['#text'], currency = sJson.NetAmount['@currency']
```

| amount | currency |
| --- | --- |
| 150.00 | USD |